# Proving constants are differentiable using the definition

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I'm currently studying differentiability at college, and I can't for the life of me understand how a constant is differentiable. I am using the definition of differentiability (as $h \rightarrow 0$ and you have $h$ at the bottom).

When $f(x) =c$ what is $f(x_0 + h)?$

I understand why x is differentiable but I can't get a hold for constants!

Thank you for reading!

Comment: $f: x \mapsto c$, then $f(x_0 + h) = c$. Was that your question?

Comment: Part of it. If $f(x_0+h) = c \ \text{and if} f(x_0) = c \ \text{then surely the limit is undefined?}$

Answer (score 3):

Notice that a constant function $f(x) = c$ $\forall x$. That is: 
\begin{equation}
f(x_0 + h) = c = f(x_0)
\end{equation}

Using the definition of differentiability: 
\begin{equation}
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x_0 + h) - f(x_0)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{c - c}{h} =\lim_{h \to 0} 0 = 0
\end{equation}

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I got to this stage in my working but surely 0/0 is undefined? Or am I missing something

Comment: @EnterpriseMathematics $\frac00$ is undefined, but $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac 0x$ is **not** undefined. Because $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac 0x = L$ if, for **very small but nonzero values** of $x$, the value $\frac0x$ is close to $0$.

Comment: $0/0$ in a limit need not be undefined, which you'll understand when you learn l'Hospital's rule.

Comment: In defining $f'(x_0)$, you are taking the limit as $h\to 0$ of a function of $h$ (i.e., the difference quotient) defined for all non-zero $h$ (obviously, the difference quotient is not defined at $h=0$, since as you point out, it is $0/0$ which is undefined). In this case, the answer above shows that the function in question is zero for all $h\neq 0$ (remove limit signs in the answer). Now, if a function is $0$ for all non-zero $h$, then its limit at $0$ is also $0$ (remember, we do not need the function to be defined at $0$ to evaluate the limit, and indeed it is not in this case).

Comment: @5xum: One of either the $L$ or the $0$ should be changed to the other.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, your problem lies a couple of lessons further back, so I'll start there:

**Limits**

What is a limit of a function? By definition, we have that $$\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = L$$
**if and only if** for every $\epsilon>0,$ there exists such a $\delta > 0$ that for all $x$ such that $0<|x-a|<\delta$, we have $|L-f(x)|<\epsilon$

What does this mean? Well, it means that the values of $f(x)$ are close to $L$ if $x$ is close to $a$. But there is an important inequality there: $0<|x-a|$. Yes, $x$ is close to $a$, but never **equal** to it. So, for example, the function $f(x)=\frac {x^2}{x}$, which is undefined at $x=0$, may still have a limit at $x=0$. In fact, that limit is $0$, because:

- Take any $\epsilon>0$
- Set $\delta = \epsilon$, and let $x$ be such that $|x-a| < \delta$ (where $a$ is of course $0$)
- Then, we have $|f(x)-0|=|\frac{x^2}{x}-0| = |x-0|=|x|<\epsilon$, and we are done

Note: the equality $|\frac{x^2}{x}-0| = |x-0|$ **only holds if $x\neq 0$, but the limit does not care about $x=0$, so we are safe.